# ¿Por qué no puedo usar mi app en un dispositivo android sin actualizar los servicios de play store?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

He creado una app que tiene registro de usuarios con `android studio` y `firebase`. Resulta que cuando un usuario intenta registrarse, le sale una notificación que le informa de que no puede usar la app sin antes actualizar los servicios de `play store`. (cuando los actualiza puede usar la app normalmente. Pero **lo que quiero es que mi app corra con cualquier versión de `play store` que el usuario tenga en su dispositivo `android`**).

He usado:

- Android Studio 2.2.0

La versión mínima de `sdk`:

- API 17

...

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.5.3'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
```

No sé si habría que cambiar algo...

Comment: puede ser cosa del firebase, que requiere la ultimas versiones de play services?

Comment: pues es una pu...da! Noto que los usuarios descargan mi app, pero escasamente se registran, ya que actualizando play services se consumen más de 33MB de datos, y eso supone un gasto económico. :-(

Comment: @Tony_Bielo entiendo lo que comentas aunque varios dispositivos por default tienen configurada la actualización únicamente en red Wi-Fi además en algún momento alguna aplicación obligaría a realizar esto.

Comment: Una pregunta importante es si tu aplicación en verdad requiere de Firebase, auth, messaging, database y storage, que realiza tu aplicación? Tal vez podrías no necesitar todas las dependencias.

Comment: Mi app es una tienda de compra-venta de objetos usados. un usuario se registra, crea un perfil con foto, puede crear anuncios con imágen y texto. tambien uso push noticications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como comenta @Webserveis, al usar librerías Firebase, requiere versiones actuales de Google Play Services, en este caso minimo la versión 9.0

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

> Google Play services updated to 9.0.2 The Google Play services version
>   9.0.2 release is now available. This release fixes a known issue with Firebase Authentication where the FirebaseAuthApi is not available on
>   some devices. A FirebaseApiNotAvailableException error occurs when
>   those devices attempt to use Authentication APIs.

Por esta razón la ejecución de tu aplicación requiere la actualización de [Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview).

Comment: Según lo que he entendido, voy a probar con 8.4. para conseguir más compatibilidad.

Comment: Prueba eso, pero ten en cuenta que si cambias a 8.4 tal vez requiera tu proyecto una versión más baja de Android Build Tools. comenta los resultados!

Comment: Como comentabas antes @Elenasys , me salió el error:  Error:(42, 0) Version: 8.4 is lower than the minimum version (9.0.0) required for google-services plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Se debe al Google Play Services que contiene muchas de las APIs que utilizamos, en tu caso Firebase. 
Pasa lo mismo cuando utilizas la API de Google Maps, Youtube, Google Drive, Google Wallet, etc.

Google Play Services recibe actualizaciones periódicas y es necesario que el usuario las actualice para que tu aplicación que contiene las versiones mas actuales de las APIs también funcionen en el dispositivo del usuario.

Comment: Eso quiere decir que no hay nada que pueda hacer?  o  puedo probar con una versión inferior de firebase. o sea, de: `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth: **9.8.0** '` lo paso a:  `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth: **4.0.0** '`

Comment: Depende mas de la versión de Google Play Services que tengan, aunque tu bajes o aumentes las versiones, realmente no sabes que versión de Google Play tiene el usuario. De todas maneras si no es tu app, sera otra la que le pedirá al usuario actualizar, por ejemplo: Youtube o Google maps